# libgdx - doing something in other thread not working

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, libgdx

My game has a stats queue, after each game the current game stats goes into the queue.
Whenever the mainmenu starts i want to upload all the game stats to a server, and this take like 1-3 seconds and I want to do this in an other thread.

My code

```
    @Override
    public void show() {
        Global.key = Global.getKey();
        // System.out.println(Stats.getJSONObject(Global.key));

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Stats.TryUploadGame1();
                System.out.println("DONE");
            }
        });
.....

}
```

But this also freezes my game.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Your current code is posting a `Runnable` instance that will be executed *by the render thread* before the next frame.  The `Gdx.app.postRunnable` API is generally used so background threads can ask for something to happen on the render thread.  You want to post a `Runnable` to execute anywhere but the render thread.

As long as your Stats code doesn't interact with OpenGL context at all (since Android OpenGL APIs assume only a single thread interacts with them), you can just post your `Runnable` on a new background thread:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() { ... }).start();
```

This should unblock your render.   (Of course, if your background thread uses a lot of CPU, it can still interfere with the render thread, but if its mostly doing blocking IO or host has spare cores, it shouldn't interfere.)

This could be improved in lots of ways (using a ThreadPool, or using Android-aware background task support), but if your stats update is relatively quick and the thread creation isn't frequent this should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Okay to do something in a other thread you need to take care of the **OpenGL context**. Inside of a different thread you cant do anything that does render stuff. You are forced to push such thing into the renderthread in any way. And you need to `synchronize` everything that can be called from the regular render thread from libgdx. For example you want to call the `.act(float delta)` from a stage from a different thread you are forced to put the stage indo an `synchronized` block.

The post runable isn't a thread. It is an runable that get executed at the beginning of the next rendercall. So it will stop the game till it's done but it is inside of the OpenGl context thread. (That's why your game stops)

So here is an example of how to use threading in libgdx. I use this inside of my game. It runs on 210 frames so 210 updatecalls per second. You can change it to as fast as possible or just to 60fps whatever you need:

```
public class GameLogicThread extends Thread {

    private GameScreen m_screen;
    private boolean m_runing;
    private long m_timeBegin;
    private long m_timeDiff;
    private long m_sleepTime;
    private final static float FRAMERATE = 210f;

    public GameLogicThread(GameScreen screen) { //pass the game screen to it.
        m_screen = screen;
        setName("GameLogic");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        m_runing = true;
        Logger.log("Started");
        while (m_runing) {
            m_timeBegin = TimeUtils.millis();
            // act of the camera
            synchronized (m_screen.figureStage) { //stage with figures
                // now figures
                if (m_screen.m_status == GameStatus.GAME) {
                    m_screen.figureStage.act(1f / GameLogicThread.FRAMERATE);
                }
            }
            m_timeDiff = TimeUtils.millis() - m_timeBegin;
            m_sleepTime = (long) (1f / GameLogicThread.FRAMERATE * 1000f - m_timeDiff);
            if (m_sleepTime > 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(m_sleepTime);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Logger.error("Couldn't sleep " + e.getStackTrace());
                }
            } else {
                Logger.error("we are to slow! " + m_sleepTime); //meight create it dynamic so if you are to slow decrease the framerate till you are not to slow anymore
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stops the thread save<br>
        */
    public void stopThread() {
        m_runing = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry) {
            try {
                this.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does update all my figures. To not cause any troubles with the rendering thread the figurestage is synchronized. (Kind of critical section)

Dont forget that you need to create a new thread every time you stopped it. so for example inside of the show you need todo this:

```
@Override
public void show() {
    super.show();
    m_logic = new GameLogicThread(this); //create a new one inside of the GameScreen
    m_logic.start(); //start the thread
}
```

Also dont forget to savestop it inside of the pause stop and so on.

```
@Override
public void dispose() {
    m_logic.stopThread();
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit late on this one, but thank you very much. This is exactly what I've been looking for and really helps show what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading)

> To pass data to the rendering thread from another thread we recommend using Application.postRunnable(). This will run the code in the Runnable in the rendering thread in the next frame, before ApplicationListener.render() is called.

So calling that method is just creating a new thread on to run on the render thread.

You may want to use standard java practice on creating threads unless this is frowned upon in libgdx because of android, that I am not sure of.

Comment: It doesn't create a new thread. It is used by another thread to add a Runnable to a queue which will be processed on the rendering thread. Runnable != Thread.